# Xamarin C# Databinding on ViewModels with multiple foreign key relations in datamodels: Picker and labels

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, foreign-keys

Oke here is the context: I have a Xamarin Application that connects to ASP.NET rest service. Currently I am working on the databinding on my views

There is a certain Data model called prestatie which has a foreingn Key Reference to the Trainer model class and another that foreign key reference to the Getuigschrift Class.

```
public class Prestatie : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Key]
    private Guid _PrestatieID;
    public Guid PrestatieID
    {
        get => _PrestatieID;
        set
        {
            _PrestatieID = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PrestatieID));
        }
    }
private string _Rekeningnummer;
public string Rekeningnummer
{
    get => _Rekeningnummer;
    set
    {

        _Rekeningnummer = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Rekeningnummer));
    }
}

private string _Rijksregisternummer;
public string Rijksregisternummer
{
    get => _Rijksregisternummer;
    set
    {

        _Rijksregisternummer = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Rijksregisternummer));
    }
}





[ForeignKeyAttribute("Trainer")]
public Guid? TrainerID
{
    get;
    set;
}
public Trainer Trainer
{
    get;
    set;
}




public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
}
```

Trainer Class:

```
public class Trainer : Persoon
{
    private Guid _TrainerID;
    public Guid TrainerID
    {
        get => _TrainerID;
        set
        {
            _TrainerID = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TrainerID));
        }
    }
public ICollection<Prestatie> Prestaties
{
    get;
    set;
}
public Getuigschrift Getuigschriften
{
    get;
    set;
}
private Guid _GetuigschriftID;
public Guid? GetuigschriftID
{

    get => _GetuigschriftID;
    set
    {
        _GetuigschriftID = (Guid)value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(GetuigschriftID));
    }
}
```

}

Now I got two ViewModels setup fto represent this data, one for an overview and the second for the Details/Editing/adding. Databinding of items is on the viewmodels, so in Theory I should make these relations up in my view models but I am uncertain on how to do this. At one hand I just need to have some labels back in the ItemViewModel, and the other hand I need sort of comobox/list/picker for the data input to just get the Foregin Key.

Solutions I have tried it something like this, but that does not seem to work.
[Xamarin ListView MVVM DataBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49128660/xamarin-listview-mvvm-databinding)

Here is a small snippet of my viewmodels, I cant post more because of the character limit.

```
public class PrestatieViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Prestatie> _prestaties;
    private readonly IPrestatieDataService _prestatieDataService;
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;


public ObservableCollection<Prestatie> Prestaties
{
    get => _prestaties;
    set
    {
        _prestaties = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Prestaties");
    }

}


public class PrestatieDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private Prestatie _selectedPrestatie;

    private readonly IPrestatieDataService _prestatieDataService;
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;


    public Prestatie SelectedPrestatie
    {
        get => _selectedPrestatie;
        set
        {
            _selectedPrestatie = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedPrestatie));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the picker's **selectedItem** with  trainer so you could pick and set the value.
Here are the code you could refer to

**xmal:**

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
       <local:PeopleViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
              <CollectionView x:Name="mycol">
                  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid ColumnDefinitions="100,* "
                       RowDefinitions="*,*">
                     <Label Text="{Binding Name}" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
                     <Picker x:Name="mypicker"  Grid.Column="1" Title="Select a Trainer"
                             TitleColor="Red"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding pgs}"
                             ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding Trainer}">
                     </Picker>
                     <Label Text="Trainer:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"/>
                     <Label
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Text="{Binding Trainer.Name}"/>
                 </Grid>
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
              </CollectionView>
```

**viewmodel:**

```
  public class PeopleViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string name;
        People trainer;
        public List<People> pgs { get; private set; } = new List<People>{new People{Name="Trainer1" },
            new People{ Name="Trainer2"} ,
        new People{ Name="Trainer3"} };

        public string Name {
            get { return name; }
            set { if (name != value)
                { name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            } }
        public People Trainer
        {
            get { return trainer; }
            set
            {
                if (trainer != value)
                {
                    trainer = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        void OnPropertyChanged(string name=null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        #endregion


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   
    }}
```